# I just noticed the faq was gone - are any links broken? was this a SE-wide thing or a CV thing?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed the link to the faq was gone (though I can see where much or perhaps even all of it is located now)

- I didn't notice the change before (am I unobservant - did I miss something I should have seen?).

Since I point to the faq a lot (well, no longer, I suppose!) I have one minor concern and then just a question out of interest:

- links to the faq itself clearly still "work" by going to the 'help' (I looked until I found one and clicked it), but does the faq going away (or rather, basically changing in form) break any old links to the interior of the faq?

(I presume not, it looks like it would have been cleanly handled but figured I'd ask).

- Was the change just in CV or everywhere?

Comment: This happened on CV a few days ago. Personally, I like the old system a little bit better, but *C'est la vie*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like "[the new Help Center replaces FAQ pages on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/150510)". Please note that old FAQ links should now point to the HC.

For more information, see this SO thread: [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center).